# Activating auto-completion in tcl

Tags: tcl

How can I add auto-completion of commands and directories on pressing `<TAB>` in TCL shell ?

I know that a tclreadline package can be downloaded, but I have no clue how to use it and integrate it in my tcl shell.

Answer (score 3):

You will find what you need at the [TclReadline](http://tclreadline.sourceforge.net/) site. They suggest putting the following in your `~/.tclshrc` file:

```
if {$tcl_interactive} {
    package require tclreadline 
    ::tclreadline::Loop
}
```

I also added the following prompt to remind me I am using Tcl Readline:

```
proc ::tclreadline::prompt1 {} { return "%% " }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look also on [tkcon](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net). I found it very user friendly. 
In addition you can work with this tool "just from the box" without additional configurations.

Comment: Good tip, but please note that it uses libtk, that requires X, and that is not readily available in certain environments, like containers.